# Set left margin for a paragraph in html

Tags: html, paragraphs

i want to start a paragraph after putting 5 spaces and all the lines beneath the first line should come in a straight line, imean all the lines in the paragraph should have 5 spaces before it starts.

I am getting this paragraph from databse.

I want a Html tag that will define left margin for a complete paragraph.

Comment: No, you want to start using css.

Comment: what do you mean by no? that a class isn't css related? or that he would be better of using repetitively `<p style="margin-left:5em;">` ?
than just adding adding a class `<p class='intend'>`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
<p style="margin-left:5em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut lacinia vestibulum quam sit amet aliquet. Phasellus tempor nisi eget tellus venenatis tempus. Aliquam dapibus porttitor convallis. Praesent pretium luctus orci, quis ullamcorper lacus lacinia a. Integer eget molestie purus. Vestibulum porta mollis tempus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
```

That'll do it, there's a few improvements obviously, but that's the basics. And I use `'em'` as the measurement, you may want to use other units, like `'px'`.

EDIT:
What they're describing above is a way of associating groups of styles, or classes, with elements on a web page. You can implement that in a few ways, here's one which may suit you:

In your HTML page, containing the `<p>` tagged content from your DB add in a new 'style' node and wrap the styles you want to declare in a class like so:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    p { margin-left:5em; /* Or another measurement unit, like px */ }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut lacinia vestibulum quam sit amet aliquet.</p>
</body>
```

So above, all `<p>` elements in your document will have that style rule applied. Perhaps you are pumping your paragraph content into a container of some sort? Try this:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .container p { margin-left:5em; /* Or another measurement unit, like px */ }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut lacinia vestibulum quam sit amet aliquet.</p>
  </div>
  <p>Vestibulum porta mollis tempus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.</p>
</body>
```

In the example above, only the `<p>` element inside the div, whose class name is 'container', will have the styles applied - and not the `<p>` element outside the container.

In addition to the above, you can collect your styles together and remove the style element from the `<head>` tag, replacing it with a `<link>` tag, which points to an external CSS file. This external file is where you'd now put your `<p>` tag styles. This concept is known as 'seperating content from style' and is considered good practice, and is also an extendible way to create styles, and can help with low maintenance.

Comment: Heh, correct answer even before I'd finished my elaboration :)P